# How to hide object by clicking on button or anywhere except the object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a toggle function that opens and hides an element by clicking on a button, but I also need to hide this element by clicking anywhere except for itself. I've tried to do so, but there is always something isn't working.

```
function displayOnClick(clickingObjId, displayObj) {
    let status = 1;
    document.getElementById(clickingObjId).onclick = function() {
        if(status == 1){
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'block';
            status = 0;
        } else if (status == 0){
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'none';
            status = 1;
        }

        return status 

    };
    document.onclick = function (e) {
        if (status !== 1 && e.target !== displayObj){ 
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'none';
            status = 1;
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that when I add second part of the code `document.onclick...`, button(clickingObjId) which should open the element stops working.

Comment: In  the `document.onclick` handler, simply check, if `e.target.closest('#clickingObjId')` exists. See [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Comment: Another way would be to check `if clickelement is not hovered` while click anywhere in document

Comment: You mean instead of checking e.target I should check if the cursor hovers over that element, if true - do nothing, if false do display: none? If that's the case I don't really know how to do it, I am new to coding :c. Also, it should only work when the value of status == 1, bc if not, the button which opens this element won't work, bc it is outside of the element. Can you please write the syntax on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Neia here are some example for your problem..

toggle function that opens and hides an element by clicking on a button and hide this by clicking anywhere except for itself...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#displayObject').hide();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('#togglerBtn').length ) {
        $("#displayObject").toggle();
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#displayObject').length ) {
        $('#displayObject').hide();
    }
});

});
```

```css
#displayObject {
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<button id="togglerBtn">Toggler</button>

<div id="content">
<div id="displayObject">
display Object
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```